# Fetching max timestamp from multiple tables into view

Tags: sql, db2

I am constructing a view by joining 2 tables A and B .
The tables have TIME_OF_CHANGE column, which holds the timestamps of insertion/updation
The view should contain the **max TIME_OF_CHANGE** that denotes the timestamps of the recent updates on table A or B
Please, suggest a way to do it

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?  Note that, unlike some other RDBMSs, the `MAX()` function in DB2 allows multiple arguments...

Comment: Thankyou, I tried out   select name, a1.id,b1.id, max(a1.TIMESTAMP,b1.TIMESTAMP) from a1 join b1
on a1.id=b1.id it works like magic :)

Answer (score 0):

CREATE VIEW vwReq
AS SELECT Field1,MAX(TIME_OF_CHANGE)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Field1;